# How to display a 'new' badge for new rows in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing a insert operation on a table. i wanted to display a **new** badge on for the new row with the new values for which i have used ng-repeat to display. Can i do that with angular js ? or should i use something else to achieve this? I want something like this

[image]

[image]

As the image shows i wanted to do some kind of highlight for the new row.by the way i am using php with angular js.

Comment: You can add Status like "Old" and "New". NO need to show it in Table. With this status, you can highlight new row. Yes, you can do it with angularjs. Use ng-class

Comment: @Pooja-G you wanted me to add the status in database table ? i dont have any column like that. for marking new and old

Comment: No, you don't need to add it in database. You just add it temporary in list (using for ng-repeat).

Comment: You can use ng-class like this
ng-class="[{issomestyleclass: rec.condition1},{isanotherstyleclass: rec.somedata==somevalue}]".
You should add something to distinguish your rows. For example you can add something to newly loaded rows, something like vm.data[id].loaded = true and then ng-class="{yellowclass: vm.item.loaded}".

Also you should somehow remove .loaded when you do your next update.

Comment: @GrayFox yeah i think i should use some flag to differentiate between the new and old thank you for the inputs and time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to define another variable in the `items` as `isNew`. So for the new data entries, you can set it as true and for the older ones, it could be false. The new sample would be

```
$scope.items.push({
  url: 'http://facebook.com/',
  name: 'Facebook',
  isNew: true
});
```

Use this to manipulate the class using `ng-class`

No need to have this variable in the database buy from your stored procedure itself, you can return a static value

FOr example

```
SELECT URL, Name, false 'IsNew' FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Yeah thank you, i got it but, as i am not such experienced can you tell me how can i use a stored procedure for returning this value?

Answer (score -1):

Just add the new value with the same structure into the array or object.

Example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('itemsController', ['$scope', controller]);
function controller($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    url: 'http://google.com/',
    name: 'Google'
  }];
  $scope.click = function()  {
    $scope.items.push({
      url: 'http://facebook.com/',
      name: 'Facebook'
    });
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="itemsController">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!-- items is an array -->
    <a ng-href="{{item.url}}">{{item.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<button ng-click="click()">Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This works because of the [scope digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) which execute on every change on the scope properties.

If you dont know how the digest works i highly recommend to read the docs :D [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)

Comment: i think you didnt get my question right. I just wanted to add a badge or highlight a newly added value row. my rows from the database :)